# Appending to specific location in XML file

Tags: c#, xml, file-io

I'm trying to append raw XML data part of a `List<string>` to a XML file as follows:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode docnode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);          
doc.AppendChild(docnode);

doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl' href=''"));

XmlElement Ver = doc.CreateElement("Run");
Ver.SetAttribute("version", "3.0");
XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("List");
elem.SetAttribute("Name", ObjectName_string);
doc.AppendChild(Ver);
doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(elem);
doc.Save(@"1.xml");

List<string> data = Event_table.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(dr=>dr.Field<string>(0)).ToList();


using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"1.xml", append:true))
        {


            writer.WriteLine("<cmList>");

            foreach (var row in data)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(row);
            }

            writer.WriteLine("</cmList>"); 
        }
```

**XML FILE:** This is how the final result should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href=''?>
<Run version="3.0" startTime="3.0" endTime="3.0">
  <List Name="ABCD" />
    <cmList>

         **// My Raw data should come here from List<string> data**



    </cmList>
</Run>
```

How can I append the RAW XML data `List<string> data` in between the element `<cmList>` I tried doeing a `write.BaseStream.Seek` but that gives me an error:

> Unable seek backward to overwrite data that previously existed in a
>   file opened in Append mode.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog many moons ago that specifically addressed how to get data from a DataSet/DataTable into XML (for use in Excel specifically).  It appears that this may help you. Just exclude the instructions that tell the XML file to open in Excel.  It is in VB.NET, so you will have to use the analogous C# code.

[DataSet to XML Blog](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/blog/1693/entry-4472-more-xml-to-excel-tricks/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand something in your example but why don't you append raw data before saving xml to file?

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode docnode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
doc.AppendChild(docnode);
doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl' href=''"));

XmlElement Ver = doc.CreateElement("Run");
Ver.SetAttribute("version", "3.0");
XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("List");
elem.SetAttribute("Name", ObjectName_string);
XmlElement cmList = doc.CreateElement("cmList");

List<string> data = Event_table.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(dr => dr.Field<string>(0)).ToList();
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var row in data)
{
    builder.AppendLine(row);
}
cmList.Value = builder.ToString();

elem.AppendChild(cmList);
Ver.AppendChild(elem);
doc.AppendChild(Ver);
doc.Save(@"1.xml");
// do something with file 1.xml
```